# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'mapper'

Tags: c#, oop, repository-pattern

I'm sure this is a basic OOP issue but I'm trying to use ContactsRepository as Base class and use its methods in the class OrganizationRepository but getting the error:
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'mapper'

//OrganizationRepository class

```
public class OrganizationRepository : ContactsRepository, IOrganizationRepository
    {

        #region fields   
        private readonly GreyWorldDB_DevEntities _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly UserManagement _userManagement;
        #endregion


        #region Ctor
        public OrganizationRepository(IMapper mapper, GreyWorldDB_DevEntities context, UserManagement userManagement)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _context = context;
            _userManagement = userManagement;
        }
        #endregion

        #region  Actions

            //Action methods
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

            //private methods
        #endregion
    }
```

//ContactsRepository Class

```
public class ContactsRepository : IContactsRepository
    {

        #region fields   
        private readonly GreyWorldDB_DevEntities _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly UserManagement _userManagement;
        #endregion

        #region Ctor
        public ContactsRepository(IMapper mapper, GreyWorldDB_DevEntities context, UserManagement userManagement)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _context = context;
            _userManagement = userManagement;
        }
        #endregion

        #region  Actions

            //Action methods
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods


        #endregion

    }
```

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'mapper' of 'ContactsRepository.ContactsRepository(IMapper, GreyWorldDB_DevEntities, UserManagement)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an instance of a derived class, the base class' constructor is called before the derived class's constructor is run. The constructors do not have to be the same between classes, but if the base class' constructor is not parameterless, you still need to pass the parameters that it requires to it:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(string name)
    {
    }
}

public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass() : base("test")
    {
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are redefining the same private fields in the base and derived class. Instead you should make them `protected`in the base, leave the base constructor to populate them, and simply pass them from the derived class. Your code should end up looking something like this:

```
public class ContactsRepository : IContactsRepository
{
    protected readonly GreyWorldDB_DevEntities _context;
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;
    protected readonly UserManagement _userManagement;

    public ContactsRepository(IMapper mapper, GreyWorldDB_DevEntities context, UserManagement userManagement)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _context = context;
        _userManagement = userManagement;
    }
}

public class OrganizationRepository : ContactsRepository, IOrganizationRepository
{
    public OrganizationRepository(IMapper mapper, GreyWorldDB_DevEntities context, UserManagement userManagement)
        : base(mapper, context, userManagement)
    {
    }
}
```